# ListView owner drawing and column auto-resizing

Tags: c#, listview, autoresize

I have a [`ListView`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.aspx) which is using owner drawing to draw additional content for some sub-items.

I've found that because this additional content takes up some additional space the list view now incorrectly calculates the column "auto resize" width, and so when someone auto-resizes some columns (e.g. by double clicking on the column resize handle) the column is resized so that it is too small, and the text in that list view is rendered with parenthases (...) at the end.

Is there a way that I can prompt the list view to ask me what size the columns should be during an auto-resize?

Answer (score 1):

There is no single message which tells you when a column is about to be auto resized. But as you've mentioned, there are only two ways the user can trigger that: double clicking on the divider, and `Ctrl-Shift-+`. You can intercept both of these and then do whatever you like.

Step #1: To intercept the double click you need to subclass `ListView` and listen for the `HDN_DIVIDERDBLCLICK` notification:

```
protected override void WndProc(ref Message m) {
    switch (m.Msg) {
        case 0x4E: // WM_NOTIFY
            if (!this.HandleNotify(ref m))
                base.WndProc(ref m);
            break;
        default:
            base.WndProc(ref m);
            break;
    }
}

protected bool HandleNotify(ref Message m) {

    const int HDN_DIVIDERDBLCLICKW = (HDN_FIRST - 25);

    NativeMethods.NMHEADER nmheader = (NativeMethods.NMHEADER)m.GetLParam(typeof(NativeMethods.NMHEADER));

    switch (nmheader.nhdr.code) {

        case HDN_DIVIDERDBLCLICKW:
            if (nmheader.iItem >= 0 && nmheader.iItem < this.Columns.Count) {
                this.AutoResizeColumn(nmheader.iItem);
                m.Result = (IntPtr)1; // prevent the change from happening
                return true;
            }
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Of course, you will have to implement `AutoResizeColumn()` to do what you want.

Step #2. To intercept the Ctrl-Shift-+, you will need to override `ProcessKeyPreview`. [This article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/22570/Overriding-Keydown-in-a-User-Control-using-Process) will show you how to do that. In your override, you would call `AutoResizeColumn()` for each column.

### Alternative approach

If you construct your `ListViewItems` such that each subitem is a string of "W"s of the same length as the data you want to owner draw, the control will use those strings to auto calculate the column this. This might be a simpler approach.

Answer (score 0):

***You can do it manually like this in the following two scenerios :***

---

- **If you want to fix a `minimumWidth` and the `maximumWidth`,**

  Use this in the `ColumnWidthChanging` event of the `ListView` :

```
   int minimumWidth = 200;
   int maximumWidth = 500;
   if (e.NewWidth  maximumWidth)
   {
      e.Cancel = true;
      e.NewWidth = maximumWidth;
   }
```

---

- **If you want to fix a `ColumnWidth` for the `ListViewColumn`, Set
  the desired `ColumnWidth`**

  Use this in the `ColumnWidthChanging` event of the `ListView` :

```
   ListView ColumnList = sender as ListView;
   e.Cancel = true;
   e.NewWidth = ColumnList.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Width;
```

Comment: This isn't really the same as the auto-resize feature.

Comment: "Auto resize feature will resize the column when you double click on the splitter." Am I right??

Comment: Yes - the column automatically resizes to be the correct width for the content - this isn't what you are doing in the above two scenarios.

Comment: The column will resize to a fixed width[set before] in what I was doing!

Comment: Thats not what the auto-resize feature does. The auto resize feature simply resizes the column to a suitable value (based on the content) when the user double clicks the resize handle for a column (or uses the Ctrl + Shift + `+` keyboard shortcut). The size of the column is not fixed however, the user is still free to resize the column to whatever width they desire.

Comment: Yes, true but you can always calculate a new size during the autoresize in the `ColumnWidthChanging` event. That will just do your work! so during auto-resize just `e.Cancel` it and set the column width to the correct one!

Comment: But without a way to detect whether or not a column width changing event is raised as a result of an auto-resize or a normal resize changing the column width in this event would also change the column width during a normal resize, effectively fixing the column width.

Comment: You can do something for that...Calculate the column width-->check if the new width is smaller or not then adjust the column width accordingly!